# What is "Temporary" file mode in Plan 9, and is it available in Linux?

Tags: go, filesystems, temp

I am manually creating a temporary file using:

```
tempDir := os.TempDir()
tempFile := filepath.Join(tempDir, "my.file")
ioutil.WriteFile(tempFile, []byte{}, os.ModeTemporary)
```

I am intentionally avoiding `ioutil.TempFile()` because I don't want a random suffix to be appended to the filename.

When browsing through the different types of permissions in the `os` package, `ModeTemporary` seemed the most fitting but is also commented with:

```
ModeTemporary                                  // T: temporary file; Plan 9 only
```

What's Plan 9 and why does only it support `ModeTemporary`?

Can I use `ModeTemporary` on normal Linux distributions as well?

Comment: Why are you avoiding `ioutil.Tempfile`? There is no "correct" mode, but Tempfile uses `os.OpenFile(name, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_EXCL, 0600)`

Comment: @JimB Edited the question to clarify

Comment: [Plan 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs) is a Unix-like OS. "Plan 9 only" means it only works on Plan 9, so no, it won't work on Linux.

Comment: Even if `ModeTemporary` was valid on your OS, are you really looking to leave the permission bits `0000`?

Comment: I don't intend on writing the file. Just creating it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Temporary" mode on Plan 9 marks the file for exclusion from daily backups. From the [`stat` man page](https://9fans.github.io/plan9port/man/man9/stat.html):

> Temporary files are not included in nightly archives (see Plan 9’s fossil(4)).

And no, this is not available on standard Linux filesystems.

Comment: Not *quite:* `extN` support "attributes" on files and directories. The `d` attribute on a file is documented as marking the file to be excluded from the consideration by the `dump(8)` utility. Looks quite like this flag. Of course, this attribute is purely a "policy thing"—that is, it does not *mandate* the kernel (or whatever) to do anything (as opponsed, to say, the `i` attribute which marks the file immutable even for root). More info can be found in the `chattr(1)` man page, for instance.